# Force Highcharts to show last x-axis label

Tags: highcharts

In the following Highcharts graph, I'd like the last label in the x-axis to be 2017 instead of hidden. That way it's crystal what the last year in the chart is.

[image]

I'm hoping there's a way to accomplish this while keeping the tick interval at 2. In other words, the first label would be 1999, and the last would be 2017.

Comment: Please provide your code.

Answer (score 1):

Use `xAxis.endOnTick` - [Doc link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.endOnTick)

```
xAxis: {
    endOnTick: true,
    showLastLabel: true // Default is true but just in case
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6gp787gu/)