# How to show first and last label of x axis Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I tried some solution on other answers but I couldn't get the result what I want.. please help me.

I want to show first x axis label and last one in highcharts.

I tried {endOnTick: true, showLastLabel: true} from this answer([Force Highcharts to show last x-axis label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48894017/force-highcharts-to-show-last-x-axis-label)) but it shows just some number on the last.. not the actual last label.

This is my x axis option

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'Month',
    // tickInterval is 5 this time
    tickInterval: <?php echo number_format($num_results/5, 0);?>,
    endOnTick: true, // it shows "25" at the end of the label. not "2019-06"
    showLastLabel: true, // Default is true though..
    labels: {
        autoRotation: 0
    },
    //I get those categories from server
    //so it could be different every time
    //but this time I just write the result of it.
    categories:  ["2017-07","2017-08","2017-09","2017-10","2017-11","2017-12","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04","2018-05","2018-06","2018-07","2018-08","2018-09","2018-10","2018-11","2018-12","2019-01","2019-02","2019-03","2019-04","2019-05","2019-06"]
}
```

expected x axis labels are
"2017-07 2017-12 2018-05 2018-10 2019-03 2019-06"

the actual result is
"2017-07 2017-12 2018-05 2018-10 2019-03 25"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh I used tickPositioner and solved it!

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'Linear',
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    tickPositioner: function() {
        var positions = [],
            ext = this.getExtremes(),
            xMax = Math.round(ext.max),
            xMin = Math.round(ext.min);

        for (var i = xMin; i < xMax; i++) {
            if (i % <?php echo number_format($num_results/3,0);?> == 0) {
                positions.push(i);
            }
        }
        positions.push(xMax);
        return positions;
    },
    labels: {
        autoRotation: 0,
    },
    categories:  ["2017-07","2017-08","2017-09","2017-10","2017-11","2017-12","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04","2018-05","2018-06","2018-07","2018-08","2018-09","2018-10","2018-11","2018-12","2019-01","2019-02","2019-03","2019-04","2019-05","2019-06"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 2 categories to show `2019-06`

```
...
categories:  ["2017-07","2017-08","2017-09","2017-10","2017-11",
              "2017-12","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04",
              "2018-05","2018-06","2018-07","2018-08","2018-09",
              "2018-10","2018-11","2018-12","2019-01","2019-02",
              "2019-03","2019-04","2019-05","2019-06","24th","the 25th"]
},
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bjksxnpf/)

Comment: but there was no data after 2019-06.. I could solve it with other way. Thank you for answering!